# Separate buttons to change password in user preferences web page

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm designing a user preferences webpage and now I've placed two save buttons, one to save a new changed password, and other to save other kind of user preferences. My doubt is that I'm not sure if this is the more accessible and usable way to implement it. 
I would hear opinions about what is the best option and why, because I haven't found any clear direction about this issue in the web.

Comment: Any reason you don't use separate forms?

Comment: This isn't an "air your opinions" kind of site. Please read the [faq].

Comment: Sorry to annoy you Cody Gray, but the question is about web design, not opinions. I've used the opinion word only to express my understandings, please don't misunderstand my words.

Comment: SpaceBeers, there isn't enough data to split the screen in two. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: How are you processing the form? PHP? JS?

Comment: OK I've retagged the question, see an example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if you've got a form like so:

```
<form action="YOUR_PAGE" method="POST">

    <label>Field 1: </label><input type="text" name="form_field_1" />
    <label>Field 2: </label><input type="text" name="form_field_2" />

    <input type="submit" name="submitFieldOneOnly" value="Submit field 1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitFieldTwoOnly" value="Submit field 2" />
</form>
```

You need to run different code depending on which button was pressed you can use the following PHP code on the page your form submits to:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitFieldOneOnly'])) {
        //Submit button one was pressed
        echo $_POST['form_field_1'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submitFieldTwoOnly'])) {
        //Submit button two was pressed
        echo $_POST['form_field_2'];
    }
?>
```

This should be more than enough to do what you're after.

Comment: Thanks SpaceBeers. I already have the form this way, but from user (accessibility) I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it.